# How can i set a limit on Fousquare API

Tags: php, api, foursquare

I'm fetching check-in's a place's from Foursquare API. But, API gets all check-in's. I need only 5 check-in's. How can I set a limit?

my code:

```php
 <?php if(!isset($_GET['code']) && !isset($_COOKIE['access_token'])) { 

 $authorizeUrl = $fsObjUnAuth->getAuthorizeUrl($redirectUri); 

} else {}

$creds = $fsObj->get("/venues/{$userId}/herenow");

$f=0;
foreach ($creds->response->hereNow as $item) {}
foreach ($item as $item2) {
foreach ($item2 as $item3) {    
$f++;
if($item3->firstName) {

echo '<div class="user-normal">';
echo '<img src="'.$item3->photo.'" class="avatar" />';
echo '<span class="username-def">'; 
echo $item3->firstName; echo ' ';
echo $item3->lastName;
echo '</span>';
echo '</div>';
if ($f==5) break;

}

;};};     ?>
```

i try this apigee.com and is working http://prntscr.com/1phdin. apigee is creating oauth_token but I don't understand how. I get "invalid oauth_token" error because I can't create my own.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an optional parameter to set the limit

[Foursquare Developer docs](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/herenow)

So for example:

`/venues/{$userId}/herenow?limit=5`

Comment: I try this but is now working.

Uncaught exception 'EpiFoursquareBadRequestException' with message '{"meta":{"code":400,"errorType":"invalid_auth","errorDetail":"Missing access credentials. See https:\/\/developer.foursquare.com\/docs\/oauth.html for details."},"response":{}}' in /satocafe/four/EpiFoursquare.php:244 Stack trace: #0 /public_html/satocafe/four/EpiFoursquare.php(208): EpiFoursquareException::raise(Object(EpiCurlManager), false) #1 //public_html/satocafe/index.php(162): EpiFoursquareJson->__get('response') #2 {main} thrown in public_html/satocafe/four/EpiFoursquare.php on line 244

Comment: You need to supply the access credentials when you make a request that relies on authentication.Like this:`oauth_token=ACCESS_TOKEN`. See [this](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/auth) docs page.

Comment: I have access_token and my query: http://prntscr.com/1pgvqo but is not working. How I get to oauth_token?

Comment: I've not used that library, but it looks like `$fsObjUnAuth->setAccessToken($_COOKIE['access_token']);`

Comment: A couple of points here. 1) `access_token` is essentially the same thing as `oauth_token`. The former is returned to you in a response from Foursquare and the latter is used as the parameter name in an API call. 2) it looks like you're calling venues/userId/herenow... userId should be replaced by a venueId if you want to see how many people are at a venue. If you want to see your own previous 5 check-ins, the endpoint is users/userId/checkins. See https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/users/checkins and https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/herenow

Comment: if access_token and oauth_token are essentially the same, why am I getting "invalid oauth_token" error when I'm using "access_token"?

Error: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'EpiFoursquareNotAuthorizedException' with message '{"meta":{"code":401,"errorType":"invalid_auth","errorDetail":"OAuth token invalid or revoked."} blablabla...

and my query: 
$creds = $fsObj->get("/venues/{$userId}/herenow?v=20120321&limit=5&oauth_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN");

OR

$creds = $fsObj->get("/venues/{$userId}/herenow?v=20120321&limit=5");

does not work either way.

Comment: `oauth_token` is just what we call the `access_token` when you're making a request; they're the same thing. Are you currently checked into the venue you're trying to get herenow for? The `limit` parameter applies to how many people we return that are currently at a venue. If you're not at a venue we don't return any people, which is perhaps why you're seeing an auth error.